# Get record count based upon Group, mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo schema like this,

[image]

I want the result for a particular user to be group+count of status field, something like that (this is wrong i know),

```
 db.timesheets.aggregate([
    {_id: user},
    {$group: {_id: "$status"}},
    {$count: 'count'}
])
```

What i want in final result is like this:

```
{ "_id" : "Saved", count: 2 }
{ "_id" : "Approved", count: 1 }
```

Currently i am fetching all records on of userid, and from code i am filtering it, not sure how to do that in mongodb query. Need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$status",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kCSGdz2_sGe)